# Can I deduct BYOD expenses from my 2019 taxes?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction

I've been searching around and all I can find is for business owners to deduct expenses from buying equipment for their employees to use, or self-employed persons to deduct their own expenses. If my company did BYOD, can I deduct at least part of the purchase price of my laptop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Unreimbursed business expenses are [no longer deductible](https://www.hrblock.com/tax-center/filing/adjustments-and-deductions/unreimbursed-employee-expenses/) by employees as of tax year 2018:

> "The Tax Cut and Jobs Act made many sweeping changes to the U.S. tax
>   system. One of the biggest changes under this new law was the
>   elimination of the deduction unreimbursed employee business expenses
>   beginning with 2018 tax returns. This effectively means that employees
>   will no longer be able to offset their taxable income by common
>   business expenses they may incur."